# creating interface in linux

Tags: linux, routing, interface

I have a tunnel with a third-party computer. This tunnel iface has the ip address of 10.244.248.126. The third-party just told me that there is an ACL that will allow only IPs from the range 10.245.1.224/28. I'd love to issue telnet -b  with and IP address of the given range, but I have no interface with a IP address in this range. How do I create such interface so that I can telnet correctly? How do I route it?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE: I can now bind thanks to the responses, but I'm getting timeout on the telnet -b. Looking at the tcpdump it seems that it is going to the wrong interface, but I'm not sure about that, because I don't know if the MAC addr should be from my virtual iface or not. Below are the ifaces, tunnel and routing tables:

https://gist.github.com/847934

https://gist.github.com/847957

https://gist.github.com/847932

Comment: Where is the tunnel established?  If it's your router (and your default gateway), you should be able to telnet to it, provided it's setup correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an alias to your network card configuration:

```
ifconfig eth0:telnet 10.245.1.225 netmask 255.255.255.240
```

You already have a tunnel, so the routing should work. Or how is the routing defined now?
You may need to add a route, but we will need more info about your connection.
First test if

```
ping 10.244.248.126
```

works. Then start your telnet session using "-b"

```
telnet -b eth0:telnet 10.244.248.126
```

Comment: `ifconfig ethN:M` is a bit outdated; nowadays it's preferable to use `ip addr add ip.ip.ip.ip/mask dev ethN`

Comment: I still have the routing issues, but your answer pushed me further. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need to define a virtual interface to be able to use the new address as bind address in telnet. Simply, this can be done using the command:

```
$ sudo ifconfig eth0:0 <your_ip_address> netmask <your_mask> up
```

Of course, you need to replace and IP and mark with the appropriate values.

For the routing part, it depends on your network setup and addressing.

Answer (score 1):

Also, telnet -b doesn't dereference IPs from interfaces (at least not on any Linux machine I've ever seen).  You actually need to specify the desired IP.

(There's an argument that it *should* work like this, and I'm sympathetic to it.  Any new socket code I write is probably going to support this as an option, and I might patch this into things.  Honestly I had no idea you could do eth0:[string], I actually thought you had to do eth0:[number])

Answer (score 0):

i think you may need a TUN/TAP interface which bridges with your physical NIC. you would need uml-utilities for that. I often use that to simulate networks. The command is *tunctl*

or, you can change your existing tunnel to reflect the new ip subnet

Edit:
Looking at your configurations, i think you need to setup a bridge(brctl?). When you make new interfaces, how can you make sure they are communicating with your physical NIC?